# How to enable c method (Stuart-Kendall $\tau_{c}$) of KendallTau?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, internals

Using `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefintions `` on `KendallTau` to investigate which method it is using I discovered that it is using the $b$ method. It uses a `$KendallVariant` variable to check for which method to run but this appears to be currently hardcoded to `"B"`. However, there is code in `KendallTau` that checks this variable for the `"A"` and `"C"` methods to calculate the respective values.

Is there some hidden *method*-type option for `KendallTau` that can be used to set the `$KendallVariant` variable to `"C"`? I am not that apt at hunting around built-in functions. I have had a look with `PrintDefintions` but nothing immediately jumps out as being a likely way to change this *hidden* variable.

Comment: Set the value of `$KendallVariant` before invoking `KendallTau`, e.g., ``Statistics`DependencyMeasuresDump`$KendallVariant = "C";
KendallTau[{1.5, 3, 5, 10}, {2, 1.25, 15, 8}]``?

Comment: @kglr Not a *method*-type option answer but it appears to do the job. (+1) Post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[kT]
kT[v_String: "B"][x__] := Block[{Statistics`DependencyMeasuresDump`$KendallVariant = v}, 
  KendallTau[x]]

sa = SparseArray[{{2, 2} -> 1, {5, 3} -> 2, {6, 1} -> 3}]; 
Row[Labeled[MatrixForm@kT[#][sa], #, Top] & /@ {"A", "B", "C"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was wondering about setting `$KendallVariant` back to its original value. The use of `Block` saves me from that (especially if some odd error occurs).  +1 while we wait for other solutions.