# How to switch Variance (and StandardDeviation) on WeightedData to use unbiased estimator for frequency weights?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, internals

For [weighted sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_variance) it appears that `Variance` (and `StandardDeviation`) on `WeightedData` uses the reliability weights formula for an unbiased estimate.  I would like to change this so that it uses the frequency weights formula for an unbiased estimate.  This change would hold both when directly called and when used behind the scenes in other functions (e.g. `Standardize`) that take `WeightedData` and use `Variance` (and `StandardDeviation`) internally.

Is there a hidden option (perhaps it can take an undocumented `Method` option) that can switch between the two formulas in the background?  I tried `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefintions `` on `Variance` but did not notice anything.

```
SeedRandom[123];
wd = WeightedData[Range[10], RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 10]];
```

then

```
N@Variance@wd
```

> ```
> 9.85538
> ```

matches the reliability weights formula result

```
rw = N@Total[wd["Weights"] (wd["InputData"] - Mean@wd)^2]/
    (Total@wd["Weights"] - (Total[wd["Weights"]^2]/Total@wd["Weights"]))
```

> ```
> 9.85538
> ```

However, I want it to use the frequency weights formula.

```
fw = N@Total[wd["Weights"] (wd["InputData"] - Mean@wd)^2]/(Total@wd["Weights"] - 1)
```

> ```
> 8.8619
> ```

For example, in `Standardize` currently it uses the reliability weights formula.

```
First@N@Standardize[wd, Mean, StandardDeviation]["InputData"]
```

> ```
> -1.24429
> ```

```
(1 - Mean@wd)/Sqrt@rw
```

> ```
> -1.24429
> ```

But I need the frequency weights for this and other functions.

```
(1 - Mean@wd)/Sqrt@fw
```

> ```
> -1.31219
> ```

Any way of switching between the formulas?  There is a way for at least one other function to switch between implementations ([126242](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126242)) so I am slightly hopeful.

Comment: a) How many samples do you have? After 20 samples, your error would be <5%, and after 100 samples, it will be less than 1% difference. How important is that 1% of Variance? Especially considering that square root of that (SD) is going to be less than half of that error. So given n=250, your sd will be 0.2% smaller than you want it to be.

Comment: b) Why not just define a custom function? That way you will never confuse the two and will have a lesser chance of making a computational mistake. Such as `WeightedVariance[wd_WeightedData] := 
  Total[wd["Weights"] (wd["InputData"] - Mean@wd)^2]/(
  Total@wd["Weights"] - 1);`

Comment: @GregoryKlopper a) The length of the weighed data will vary and will not be large; perhaps 20 to 40 items long. b) As I mentioned above, it is not just `Variance` but also other [Descriptive Statistics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DescriptiveStatistics.html) that will use the variance and/or standard deviation functions internally that I suspect will return different values to what I am seeking as a result.  I would rather not recode all these functions.

Comment: Consider that weights could all be so small, that they do not even add up to 1. In which case Total@weights-1 is not only absolutely meaningless, but is NEGATIVE! You're trying to decrease degrees of freedom, so what you can do is trim your weights (cut off largest and smallest and compute that way). A better method - you can compute the mean of totals of all combinations of weights, having one removed.

Comment: `Variance@wd * Total@wd["Weights"] /Mean[
 Total /@ Table[Delete[wd["Weights"], i], {i, Length@wd["Weights"]}]]` gives output of 7.63889 for your example above. Close enough to 7.333 and is actually far more statistically meaningful.

Comment: You can change meaning of Variance using local context, however, I don't think that will have any impact on other functions as they use an optimized direct call to the compiled library rather than calling the high level Variance[] function.

Comment: @GregoryKlopper Weights will be always be greater than one as they are frequency weights (have updated example to a more representative case).  Thanks for your comments. I'll hold out to see if something comes up.